# how to define ref data as class type in vue3 with ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm, vuejs3, typescript-class

I want to use ref to create a class . It can be used as a class instance which can be called by `.`

in my ts file

```js
export default declare class Cropper {
  ....
}
```

in my vue3 file

```
const cropper =ref<Cropper||undefined||null>()
```

but it dosen't work
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `|` union types in TypeScript isn't the same as `||` (logical OR) in JavaScript.

It should be:

```
const cropper = ref<Cropper|undefined|null>()
```